# Howto copy object from model A to model B

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model classes:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    [many fields]

class ArticleArchive(models.Model):
    [same fields as Artilce model]
```

and I want to get objects from Article table and move it to ArticleArchive table:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(date__year=2011)
for art in articles:
    [and there moving objects]
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(date__year=2011).values()
for art in articles:
    ArticleArchive.objects.create(**art)
```

Comment: +1 for create, but strictly speaking, this is duplicating rows not moving them.

Comment: For better performance, it's better to use  `ArticleArchive.objects.bulk_create(...)`.

Answer (score 6):

For better performance, it's better to use `ArticleArchive.objects.bulk_create(...)`:

```
articles = list()
for article in Article.objects.filter(date__year=2011).values():
    articles.append(ArticleArchive(**article))
if (len(articles) > 0):
    ArticleArchive.objects.bulk_create(articles)
```

And then, if you want to delete the articles from the original table (optional):

```
Article.objects.filter(date__year=2011).delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't seem to get the crust of your problem but you can simple do this in the loop:

```
obj, created = ArticleArchive.objects.get_or_create( your fields )
```