# On approval How to copy an object from App A.Model A to App B.Model B create new object and update one field in App B Model B

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i am new to django and python. 
Python 3.8.2 
Django 3.0.5

i have two apps , App-A with Model-A  and App-B with Model-B
i am using class detail view to show App-A Model-A object so user can review the data.

```
class ModelADetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = AppAModelA
```

if the data is good the user on click  will:

1. Create a new object in App-B Model-B,
2. Copy the App-A Model-A object to the same field names in App-B Model-B
3. Update a Customer_id field with  unique customer ID number in App-B Model-B.  (check the latest assigned ID and add +1 to create  a sequential unique customer ID in App-B Model-B )
4. After all ok, show the detail page of the newly created object in App-B Model-B

any ideas?

currently i am reading 
[Howto copy object from model A to model B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697575/howto-copy-object-from-model-a-to-model-b) 
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#proxy

they are similar however they are not complete and old.

thank you for your help.